# Adding text to Image using HTML5 / CSS

Tags: css, html, banner

I tried to make a banner for my website I'm creating, but when I add it to my website, it turns out really bad with the text. I'm wondering if I can add text to my banner using HTML5 and / or CSS.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Play - Learn - Grow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body class="body">

        <span class="banner_h">
            <img src="Images\Top_Banner_4.png" alt="Banner" height="150" width ="1240"/>
        </span>

        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="membership.html">Become a Member</a></li>
                <li><a href="borrow.html">Borrow Toys</a></li>
                <li><a href="policies.html">Our Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <span class="banner_l">
            <img src="Images\Side_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <span class="banner_r">
            <img src="Images\Side_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <h2 class="headers">Welcome to the Home Page!</h2>

        <div class="container">

            Our aim is to provide the children of the community with an ever-changing variety of educational and fun toys to enhance
            their cognitive, social, emotional and physical development in the important first six years of their lives.

            <br><br><span class="Links">Be sure to check out our Wikispace site with more information <a href="http://mysocialmediatools-pn.wikispaces.com/">here</a>!</span>

        </div>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy 2013
        </div>


      </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Entire Document CSS */
html{
    height: 100%;
}
/* Header CSS */
.headers{
    color: #FFD89A;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Body CSS */
.body{
    background-color: #61B329;
    height: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 50em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    height: 50%;
}
/* Navigation CSS */
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00B2EE;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 14.28%;
    float: left;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Banner / Picture CSS / Text in Images */
.banner_l{
    float: left;
}
.banner_r{
    float: right;
}
.banner_h{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner_h img{
    width: 100%;
}
/* Footer CSS */
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}
/* Link CSS */
a:link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: #028482;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active{
    background-color: #FCDC3B;
    color: #AA00FF;
    text-decoration: overline;
}
.Links A:hover{
    color: #028482;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

I'm trying to center / centre my text on the banner, with a white coloured font (font can be varied). What do I have to do to make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: You should be making the image a CSS background, not an inline image, and placing text over top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the kind of text you will be adding to the banner. If you want to add text that will be static (as in, it will never or rarely change) and want to add custom fonts, you should probably edit the image in Photoshop.

On the other hand, if the content in the banner will change constantly, then I would suggest adding the image as a background. Your banner h class would look something like this:

```
.banner_h{
    display: block;
    width: *actual pixel size of the banner*;
    height: *actual pixel size of the banner*;
    background: url('*location of file*') no-repeat;
}
```

If you leave the width to a percentage what will happen is that the div will not have anything inside of it and thus will not show the banner, so you need to figure out what the actual width and height of the banner is and put it in this CSS declaration so that it shows the banner.

Once you have done this, delete the image from the  tag and replace it with the content you wish to add.

Comment: Well, I tried the code, but even with the width being the actual pixel dimension, the banner disappeared, with the text remaining in the top left hand corner, over where the banner should have been. I guess I'll have to work around it, and add an image with the text. Thanks!

Comment: I see where my mistake was, take out the "none" from the background declaration. That should fix it.

Comment: Well, I did that, but the output went very out of shape - 'wonky', the top banner did not show up, and the side banners were stretched horizontally instead of vertically. It's okay, I'll just create the image with the text, and work around it by tweaking. But thanks for clearing a few doubts for me! Much appreciated!